# quarkusDev is not running tests

Tags: quarkus

New to Quarkus here. Trying the hello world application in Kotlin and gradle. It runs fine, however, 'quarkusDev' doesn't seem to find any of the tests in src/test/kotlin/... folder.

Pressing 'r' in the quarkusDev menu simply says 'No tests found'. Running './gradlew clean test' does run the tests though.

my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.5.0"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.5.0"
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-jib'
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.5.2'

    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}

group 'com.testgroup'
version '0.0.0'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.ws.rs.Path")
    annotation("javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped")
    annotation("io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    kotlinOptions.javaParameters = true
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

Anyone has ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Mind opening an issue?